# Spring Data - PagingAndSortingRepository with custom query (HQL)?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Trying to mix PagingAndSortingRepository with custom queries, no luck..

Custom repo:

```
public interface SiteRepositoryCustom
{
    public List<SitesDbRecord> getActiveSites();
}
```

Impl repo:

```
@Repository
public class SiteRepositoryImpl implements SiteRepositoryCustom
{
    private static final Logger logger = ...

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public List<SitesDbRecord> getActiveSites()
    {
        logger.info( "getActiveSites start" );

       try
       {
          String hql = "select s from SitesDbRecord s where s.isActive = true";

          return em.createQuery( hql ).setMaxResults( Integer.MAX_VALUE ).getResultList();
       }
       catch ( Exception e )
       {
          logger.error( "getActiveSites failed.", e );

          return null;
       }
   }
}
```

The repo injected to the service:

```
public interface SiteRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<SitesDbRecord, Integer>, SiteRepositoryCustom  {
    public List<SitesDbRecord> getActiveSites( Pageable pageable );
    public List<SitesDbRecord> getActiveSites();
}
```

If I just extend CrudRepository (without the Pageable method) then all is OK. Trying to extend PagingAndSortingRepository (with or without the Pageable method) then Spring fails to boot with

```
PropertyReferenceException: No property getActiveSites found for type SitesDbRecord!
```

What is the correct way to use PagingAndSortingRepository with custom queries? Probably got it wrong, but I assumed it's Spring responsibility to provide the handling of paging/sorting.

Comment: Did you try with @Query annotation?

Comment: Doing my first steps with Spring, not familiar with this.. should help?

Comment: Because `getActiveSites( Pageable pageable )` has no implementation. Just delete this method or move it into `SiteRepositoryCustom` and implement it in `SiteRepositoryImpl `.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `SitesDbRecord` has boolean property named `active` it should be:

```
public interface SiteRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<SitesDbRecord, Integer> {
    public List<SitesDbRecord> findByActiveIsTrue( Pageable pageable );
    public List<SitesDbRecord> findByActiveIsTrue();
}
```

There is no need to extend your Custom repository, just implement PagingAndSortingRepository

Comment: Must I follow this naming convention? And if following this conventions, then no need to provide implementation for both methods?

Comment: Yes if you prefer and Yes to your second question . It’s a fast way to implement your repository layer.

Comment: What if we need custom code, like filtering on 10+ fiels along with Pageable support?